# Resharper - Code Cleanup - Sorting methods.. Can I make exception that will be last?

Tags: sorting, exception, methods, resharper, code-cleanup

Is there an option for exception for cleaning methods?

I have methods Serialize and Deserialize. I would like them to be at the end of the file after `Resharper` sorts other methods.

Is this doable only with `Resharper`?

Comment: I don't know if there's a setting, but an alternative would be to do the cleanup and then drag those two methods to the bottom of the list in the File Structure window, which will move the methods to the end of the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try updating `ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | File Layout` to get the sorting you need:

1. You have already had an entry to match Methods:

   ```
   <Entry DisplayName="Methods">
     <Entry.Match>
       <Kind Is="Method" />
     </Entry.Match>
     <Entry.SortBy>
       <Name />
     </Entry.SortBy>
   </Entry>
   ```
2. Now you need to exclude "Serialize" and "Deserialize" name from matching in the current block:

   ```
   <Entry DisplayName="Methods">
     <Entry.Match>
       <And>
         <Kind Is="Method" />
         <Not>
           <Or>
             <Name Is="Serialize" />
             <Name Is="Deserialize" />
           </Or>
         </Not>
       </And>
     </Entry.Match>
     <Entry.SortBy>
       <Name />
     </Entry.SortBy>
   ```

   [image]
3. Then add a new Entry below "Methods" entry to match "Serialize" and "Deserialize" methods:

   ```
     <Entry DisplayName="Deserialize/Serialize Methods">
       <Entry.Match>
         <And>
           <Kind Is="Method" />
            <Or>
               <Name Is="Serialize" />
               <Name Is="Deserialize" />
            </Or>
         </And>
       </Entry.Match>
     </Entry>
   ```

   [image]

Comment: Omg thank you so much. This is so awesome answer! And also great cleanup system from ReSharper.